# problemas al intentar obtener el año de un campo de tipo DateTime con EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

En mi API tengo un controlador donde filtro unos datos en función del año tal que así sin ningún problema:

```
return await _context.Ofertas.Where(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year == year).OrderBy(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum).ToListAsync();
```

Y en la entidad devuelta el campo FechaPresentacionFulcrum esta declarado así:

```
public DateTime FechaPresentacionFulcrum { get; set; }
```

Ahora intento hacer lo mismo con otra entidad donde la fecha de la que quiero filtrar por año es un campo que admite nulos y por lo tanto la declaro así:

```
public DateTime? FechaAval  { get; set; }
```

y este hecho hace que no me deje usar el método year

[image: error]

y no se como poder filtrar entonces por este campo

Alguna idea por favor?

Salu2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo **DateTime?** es un tipo de datos **nulleable** por lo que su tratamiento es diferente al tipo de dato **DateTime**, por tanto para llegar a la **propiedad Year** o a cualquier otra deberás poner:

```
miFecha.Value.Year;
```

Y para ver si tiene un valor puedes usar la **propiedad HasValue**:

```
if(miFecha.HasValue)
{
   //Hacer algo
}
```